# Drag and drop Javascript HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a drag and drop feature using javascript and HTML5, no jQuery. And I just cannot see what is wrong. Been looking at this for a long time and can't see where i failed. Can someone find it?

```
    function doFirst(){
    mypic = document.getElementById('dragapple');
    mypic.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);

    leftbox = document.getElementById('leftbox');
    leftbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e){e.preventDefault}, false);
    leftbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){e.preventDefault}, false);
    leftbox.addEventListener("drop", dropped, false);
}
function startDrag(e){
    var code = '<img id="dragapple" src="stealeripsum.png">';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}
function dropped(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    leftbox.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
}
window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

Thanks

Comment: `e.dataTransfer.gegData('Text');`. `gegData`?

Comment: What does it do? Or not do?

Comment: with this you should be able to drag and drop a picture from 1 div to another.

Comment: `dragapple` only works on Mac ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always the little things that catch us in the end.  Inside your definition for the "dragover" event listener, you need to provide an argument list `()` to e.PreventDefault:

```
leftbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
leftbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
```

That way, the browser will stop the default event response (which is to dis-allow dropping) and let your drop operation complete.  Here's my [silly jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/9Kp7a/10/show/) illustrating success.  The blue square is the `#dragapple`.

Comment: Finally! I'm been wracking my brain on this. Thanks for ending my misery. I knew the `drop` event wasn't firing but was at a loss as to why.

Comment: @KristianDaugaard It's the `()` parens at the end of `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Not in the code you included. It just says `e.preventDefault` with no `()`.

Comment: oh THANK YOU!! all i needed was (); in my prevent default function! Finally!

Comment: LOL, it's technically not a syntax error. e.preventDefault returns the function itself, but then does nothing. It's a logic error.

Answer (score 3):

`.gegData('Text')` or `.getData('Text')`?

```
function dropped(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   leftbox.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
}
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the question. That is "getData" in the actual code and it doesn't work still :)

Comment: The image is draggable, it does not have the attribute, but that should not be needed.

Comment: img doesnt require draggable="true", its default

Comment: Well, what about appending the element to the target instead of setting it as the `innerHtml`? `var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');` `e.target.appendChild(data);` Like http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: i guess i could do that, it is just very frustrating. I have been following a video tutorial for this script, and it does simply not work for me, and i have checked and matched the code 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

The html5 drag and drop api has a lot of bizarre edge cases. I just wrote a very general low-level api that makes drag-and-drop easy. Here's how you'd do it in your example:

```
function doFirst(){
    var mypic = document.getElementById('dragapple')
    dripDrop.drag(mypic, {
      image: true,
      start: function(setData) {
        setData('Text', '<img id="dragapple" src="stealeripsum.png">')            
      }
    })

    var leftbox = document.getElementById('leftbox')
    dripDrop.drag(leftbox, {
      drop: function(data) {
        leftbox.innerHTML = data.Text        
      }
    })
}

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

Check it out here: https://github.com/fresheneesz/drip-drop

Answer (score -1):

You need to make ondragover and ondrop events to the element that receives the dragged, and the dragged element need to be draggable="true".

ex:

```
<div ondragover="allowDrop(event);" ondrop="drop(event);">

function allowDrop(x) { x.preventDefault(); }

function drop(x) {  x.preventDefault(); var data=x.dataTransfer.getData("text"); ... }
```

Comment: a dragover is not needed for the drop effect. Javascripts drop effect and dragover effect are two different functions. dragover is mostly only for styling in my case and i haven't styled it yet. And about the draggable true, that is not the problem, since it is default.

Comment: @KristianDaugaard have you even tried? in my app the preventDefault is required to release the object.

Comment: I just tried removing my preventDefault()'s and to no help. I think i might have to go with the inline drop attrubute, although i was trying to avoid it.

Comment: @KristianDaugaard have you tried to change it from img to a simple text to see if it works?